# iFrame Not Closing Properly In jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, video, iframe

Right now, I have a video set up within an iFrame via jQuery UI.  In Firefox I have no problems, but for IE and Chrome, the audio continues despite closing the pop-up dialog.

Is there a way around this in the jQuery UI code?

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openDialog(url) {
        $("<div class='popupDialog'>Loading...</div>")
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                width: '900',
                height: '900',
                modal: true,
                title: 'Bonus Features'
            }).bind('dialogclose', function() {
                jdialog.dialog('destroy');
            }).load(url, function() {
                $(this).dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] );
            });

        adjustJQueryDialogOverlay();
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center']);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `beforeClose` to the dialog to remove the element:

```
   $("<div class='popupDialog'>Loading...</div>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            width: '900',
            height: '900',
            modal: true,
            title: 'Bonus Features',
            beforeClose: function(){   $(this).remove();   }
        }).load(url, function() {
            $(this).dialog("option", "position", ['center', 'center'] );
        });
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your awesome help.  It works, and it's very much appreciated.  I've been asking for days now!

Comment: By the way, why was this removed?  Just wondering.

        }).bind('dialogclose', function() {
            jdialog.dialog('destroy');